# List birthdays in the order they will come from today

Tags: awk, perl, date, sort, split

I have a text file containing birthdays:

```
1/23 Horace
3/1 Taraneh
7/14 Valerian
11/31 Carmen
```

I want to display the birthdays **from today's date**.
For example if today is 4/7 (April 7th):

```
7/14 Valerian
11/31 Carmen
1/23 Horace
3/1 Taraneh
```

How to do this in a bash script?

I have found how to split a text file based on a pattern *(I could then concatenate the splits in the opposite order)* but here the trick is that today's date might be absent, or might be the birthday of several people.

Note: all dates are valid dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
date +'%m/%d 0000' |
  sort -nt/ -k1 -k2 - birthdays.txt |
  awk '$2 == "0000" {past_today = 1; next}
       past_today {print; next}
       {next_year = next_year $0 RS}
       END {printf "%s", next_year}'
```

That is, insert a `04/07 0000` line (`date +%-m/%-d` would output `4/7` with some `date` implementations but is not portable, and `04/07` works just as well) before sorting by date, and then have `awk` move the lines that are before that one to the end.

```
sort ... - birthdays.txt
```

sorts both its stdin (represented by `-`, here a pipe that is fed by `date`) and the content of `birthdays.txt`.

We set the key separator to `/` with `-t/`, `-k1` specifies a sort key that runs from start to end of the line (in essence, `-k1` specifies the full line as a sort key), and `-k2` a sort key that starts from the first character after the first `/` to the end of the line, but with `-n`, those are interpreted as numbers, so only the initial sequence of digits matters.

(the above would work with any Bourne-like shell (including `bash`), no need to install `bash` just for that).

Comment: Please explain how does `sort` combine both the contents of `birthdays.txt` and the output of `date` piped into it in a single output.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

First change "/" in space and sort

```
sed 's|/| |' data | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n >out.tmp
```

Next, output the next dates before and the previous after

```
awk -v m=4 -v d=7 '$1 > m || $1 == m && $2 >= d' out.tmp
awk -v m=4 -v d=7 '$1 < m || $1 == m && $2 <  d' out.tmp
```

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: strange, it gives me the right answer. Probably a different flavour of "sort". Anyway no problem, you have an accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, your answer works too, thanks!

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation how it works.